# Search non-escaped single quote

Tags: regex, ocaml

I need to write a function to search for single quotes (') while skipping escaped quotes (\'). I know I can do a patten search using a function like this:

```
   let contains string pattern =
     begin
     let re = Str.regexp_string pattern
     in
       try ignore (Str.search_forward re string 0); true
       with Not_found -> false
     end
```

But how do I only search for non-escaped quote?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a non-escaped quote is one that's at the beginning of the input or is not preceded by a backslash. Unfortunately, special characters in OCaml regular expressions are marked by backslashes, and backslashes need to be doubled in an OCaml string. So you get something like the following:

```
let neq = "\\(^\\|[^\\]\\)'"
```

It just says "(the beginning of the input or a non-backslash) followed by a quote".

Don't use `Str.regexp_string`. Its purpose is to produce a regular expression that matches a given string exactly. You want to use a "real" regular expression. So use `Str.regexp`.

As a side comment, if you really just want to find unescaped quote characters (rather than learning about regular expressions), it would be much easier just to look for quote characters and then test the previous character to see if it's a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

The `String.Escaping` module in Core (make sure to install Core, and do an `open Core.Std` first) lets you do just what you want here.

```
utop[9]> String.Escaping.index ~escape_char:'\\'  "a\\'sdfde" '\'';;
- : int option = None
utop[10]> String.Escaping.index ~escape_char:'\\'  "a'sdfde" '\'';;
- : int option = Some 1
utop[11]> String.Escaping.index ~escape_char:'\\'  "asdfde" '\'';;
- : int option = None
```